# Hardwood floor to french door transition

Tags: flooring

I am installing solid 3/4 inch hardwood flooring. How do I transition it to a french door. The height of the wood flooring and door threshold are the same, but there is no clearance for the door opening for any molding that would be above floor height.

Comment: Often doors need to be trimmed off on the bottom for this type of situation. A picture would help though.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing. In some cases it looks OK for the wood to but up next to the threshold.  If the doors are metal, like exterior doors sometimes are, then they can't be cut. You have to remove the whole frame and raise them by adding a spacer underneath. I recommend pressure treated plywood. I have done one door and have 3 more to go. If they are wood and can be cut, the I would trim off the bottom of the doors to clear the floor plus a entry mat / rug.

Comment: This is right on.  I suggest adding some felt or a rubber trim piece to the bottom of an entry door.